# Django record and save mp4

Tags: javascript, django, video, mediarecorder

I'm new to Django. I'm trying to record a video in the browser than automatically save that to the server as an mp4 file. I managed to do it, but the videos are sent as a blob and saved in the database. But I would need an mp4 file on the server. For recording I'm using MediaRecorder. BTW this only needs to work on desktop, not on mobile.

This is my js code:

```
const videoElem = document.getElementById('stream-elem')

var startBtn = document.getElementById('start-stream')
var endBtn = document.getElementById('stop-media')

console.log("recorder");

var recorder;

const settings = {
    video: true,
    audio: true
}

startBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log("StartStream button is clicked");
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(settings).then((stream) => {
        console.log(stream);
        videoElem.srcObject = stream

        recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
        console.log(recorder);

        recorder.start();

        const blobContainer = [];

        recorder.ondataavailable =  (e) => {
            blobContainer.push(e.data)
        }

        recorder.onerror = (e) => {
            return console.log(e.error || new Error(e.name));
        }

        recorder.onstop =  (e) => {
            console.log(window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(blobContainer)));
            var newVideoEl = document.createElement('video')
            newVideoEl.height = '400'
            newVideoEl.width = '600'
            newVideoEl.autoplay = true
            newVideoEl.controls = true
            newVideoEl.innerHTML = `<source src="${window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(blobContainer))}"
             type="video/mp4">`
            document.body.removeChild(videoElem)
            document.body.insertBefore(newVideoEl, startBtn);

            var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append('blobFile', new Blob(blobContainer));

            fetch('/upload', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formdata
            }).then(()=>{
                alert('streamed video file uploaded')
            })
        }
    })
})

endBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    videoElem.pause();
    recorder.stop();
})
```

And this is my view function:

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload(request):
    video = request.FILES['blobFile']
    video_upload = VideoUpload()
    video_upload.video = video
    video_upload.name = request.user.username
    video_upload.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

With these I can record the video and save it in the DB as a blob. So how can I save an mp4 file to the server or convert the blob into an mp4 file? What I'm trying to achieve is to do a transcription of the videos. But I can't pass the blob to something like whisper. I need a file for that.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

I tried saving a video file to the server. I saved a blob.